# swift 3 - declated function doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm learning **`Switf 3`** on **`Xcode 8`** now and I got stuck on a little app which basically just shows a webpage in a `webView` element. The only addtion function I try to realize is that external urls get open as shared application (eg. Safari).

As there are plenty example in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) I think I found all the elements I need to make it working, but somehow the `func webView` which checks the `url` doesn't get called.

Here is my code form the `ViewController.swif` so far:

```m
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")
        debugPrint(url!)
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }

    // [...]

    func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: URLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        debugPrint("func webView has been called")
        debugPrint(request.url!)
        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
            if (request.url!.host! == "stackoverflow.com"){
                return true
            } else {
                //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
                UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!)
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Where is my logistical mistake?

Comment: Have you tried setting `delegate = self` before loading the request?

Comment: Yes that's where I had it original... just for testing I moved it down. I will correct that in the question here...

Comment: **Additional note** It's important to check `request.url!.host != nil` otherwise the app has a problem with url request without host like `mailto`.

Comment: Why the negative voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the delegate method in Swift 3 is wrong:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

Comment: that's it! Thanks so much, it really confusing as a beginner that the syntax of Swift 3 has change so much... so most of the code example doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: Delegate methods in Swift 3 which are bridged from Objective-C and are related to views have always a underscore after the opening parenthesis and the parameter types are generally non-optional or regular optional (`?`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**EDIT**

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        debugPrint("func myWebView has been called")
        debugPrint(request.url!)
        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
            if (request.url!.host! == "stackoverflow.com"){
                return true
            } else {
                //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
                UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!)
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: This option is already set, its only to allow non secured contents like form `http` links. That's not what I'm looking for!

Comment: Yes that's it! But [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389354/3001970) was faster!

Comment: Yeah net problem. Btw thanks for up vote. Happy coding :)